# Submit button stuck on processing on ajax mailer form / possible to do redirect

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

I'm very new to ajax, php. and I've looked at the other suggestions and still not sure if I found my answer. My problem is I have an ajax form that sends an email. The email function  submits fine (get 200 response code) and is received, but the submit button gets stuck on "sending..."text. The form is connected to google captcha, so not sure if that might be the reason why it's hanging.

Additionally, what I would really like to do is have the the page redirect(refresh) to a different page on the site itself.  Any help, insight would be much appreciated. Again, I'm very new to this and trying to fix on the fly, with the few things I do know.

Below is the code I'm using:

HTML/JS:

```
    <form id="contact_form" method="post" action="mailer.php">
         
        <div class="hiddenFields">
          <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
          <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="17" />
          <input type="hidden" name="RET" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="URI" value="services" />
          <input type="hidden" name="recipients" value="XXXXXXXXX"
          />
          <input type="hidden" name="user_recipients" value="XXXXXXX" />
          <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
          <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="replyto" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="input_wrap">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required" />
        </div>
           <div class="input_wrap">
          <label for="name">Company</label>
          <input type="text" id="company" name="company" />
        </div>
        <div class="input_wrap">
          <label for="from">Email</label>
          <input type="text" id="from" name="from" class="required email" />
        </div>
        <div class="input_wrap">
          <label for="message">Message</label>
          <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" data- 
     callback="onReCaptchaSuccess"></div>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
     
      </form>
     
    </div>
  </div>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
    FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="static/js/libs/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('input, textarea').focus(function () {
        var $label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
        $label.hide();
      });
      $('input, textarea').blur(function () {
        var $label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
        if (!$(this).val().length) $label.show();
      });

      $('html').on('click', function (e) {
        var clicked = $(e.target);

        if (clicked[0].id == 'submit') {
          $('#contact_form').validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
              submitemail();
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });

    function submitemail() {
      var _submit = $("#submit");
      _submit.val("Sending . . .");
      _submit.attr("disabled", "disabled");

      var postData = $("#contact_form").serializeArray();
      var formURL = $("#contact_form").attr("action");
      $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
          dataType:"json",
        data: postData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          //data: return data from server
          console.log(data.status);
          var status = data.status
          if (status == "success") {
            _submit.val("Submitted Successfully");
            
          } else {
            _submit.val("Error with server");
          }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("Our email server isn't responding");
    
          
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

```
    <?php



    // My modifications to mailer script from:
    // http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
    // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
       $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $company = $_POST["company"];
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["from"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }


        if(!$captcha){
          echo 'Please check the the captcha form.';
          exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "XXXXX";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo 'Please check Recaptcha';
        } else {
          echo '';
        }

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "email@gmail.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "Subject from $email";

        // Build the email content.
       $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content = "Company: $company\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $email <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    
       ?>
```

Comment: You could try [using PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that you tagged this question with. It includes a code example showing [how to send via an ajax call](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform-ajax.phps).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error while handling the result you get from the AJAX call:

You try to get `status` inside of the `data` variable. `data` is just the body of the response from the server, in your case everything you `echo` in PHP.

This should be a working solution:

```js
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   //data: return data from server
   var status = jqXHR.status
   if (status == 200) {
      _submit.val("Submitted Successfully");
      // Redirect:
      window.location.href = "/success";
   } else {
      _submit.val("Error with server");
   }
},
```

As you can see, I changed `data.status` to `jqXHR.status`. This returns the HTTP Status code, so you have to check for `200` (That's what you've set in PHP and what is used for successful requests).

Also, I added `window.location.href = "/success";`, that's where you can redirect to another page.

Comment: thanks @EinLinus, I updated what to what you have above and unfortunately still exhibiting the same issue, and redirect did not take on submit. any other ideas?

`success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          //data: return data from server
          var status = jqXHR.status
          if (status == 200) {
            _submit.val("Submitted Successfully");
             // Redirect:
      window.location.href = "received.html";
          } else {
            _submit.val("Error with server");
          }
        },
`